# Decentralized peer to peer identity verification

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, identity, p2p

Are there any existing methods for decentralized peer-to-peer identity verification without using any central entity for public-key signing. An example scenario is as follows.
We have a peer-to-peer system where each node has to verify the identity of another node. And the nodes won't use a central entity (like a Cert Authority for public-key signing). A simple solution would be to have all the nodes' public-keys baked in to every node during the creation/installation phase. But whenever new nodes are created or deleted, this has to be updated (which is an expensive step by the nature of the node's hardware/software design). Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here by "access to a central entity." Typically verification does not require access to the CA. It just requires that the public keys to have been signed by the CA at some point in the past, and for the nodes to trust the CA's cert. There's no particularly need for a "CA server." Certificate verification doesn't even require a network.

Comment: I meant the node won't be using any central entity for public-key signing. I've now corrected the wording.

Comment: You must have *some* ingredient for each node that the node itself has no control over, typically a cryptographic signature from a trusted party. In TLS it's the signature by one or more CAs. In PGP it's the signature from one or more other persons (or nodes if you will) who are already trustworthy. I trust Bob's key because Alice trusts it, and I trust Alice because we met in person and she has my signature to proof that fact. You have to find a mechanism for representing this "meeting in person" step.

Comment: Also consider that TLS CAs are not necessarily centralized. You can distribute a number of intermediate CA certs, for instance, and there's things like cross-signing where multiple CAs together vouch for another cert.

Comment: It depends heavily here on what it takes for you to feel confident that a node is "verified." It can be "I trust all nodes to introduce themselves" (no verification), "I've seen this node before" (ssh-style), "I trust some central entity to introduce nodes" (CA), "I trust known nodes to introduce new nodes" (web-of-trust, but that just pushes the problem back a step), "I trust a fixed list" (baking in a list of identities), but it all depends on what your trusted entity is. It's not very clear what kind of answer would satisfy this question. "Better solution" depends on your entire problem.

Comment: There is not a word wrong in the comment of Rob above. You have - in the end - decide yourself what you're going to trust. And this is not a question of programming, so it is off topic for stackoverflow for that reason alone.